# Prediction using Keras NLP

Tags: python, numpy, keras, neural-network, nlp

I am a beginner in the field of Neural Networks.

I am trying to implement an LSTM model for predicting the secondary structure of a protein from a given primary sequence. The base kernel on which my program is based can be found on Kaggle - https://www.kaggle.com/helmehelmuto/secondary-structure-prediction-with-keras

I successfully trained the model, saved the model to a pickle file, and I am able to use the pickle file to load weights to my model and make predictions as well. However, these predictions are on the test set which was created by the **test_train_split** function in Keras.

I aim to feed in a String containing the sequence of a protein and get its secondary structure prediction.

The code uses Tokenizer to convert the data (the protein sequences) from the dataset into a *numpy.ndarray* which is used for making predictions.

The part where I am stuck is, taking a string as input(some protein sequence) and converting it into the same class and then making predictions on it. 
I have tried using the same method the Kaggle Kernel author used for converting the data from the .csv file to a numpy.ndarray but I get an error - 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'.

I would be grateful if someone could guide me here, converting strings to the objects which are used for prediction in the code.

Code (works fine, predictions made directly on the test set generated by test_train_split):

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\2018-06-06-ss.cleaned.csv')
df.len.hist(bins=100)
print(df.shape)

def seq2ngrams(seqs, n=3):
    return np.array([[seq[i:i+n] for i in range(len(seq))] for seq in seqs])

maxlen_seq = 128
input_seqs, target_seqs = df[['seq', 'sst3']][(df.len <= maxlen_seq) & (~df.has_nonstd_aa)].values.T
input_grams = seq2ngrams(input_seqs)
print(len(input_seqs))

from keras.preprocessing import text, sequence
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.utils import to_categorical

tokenizer_encoder = Tokenizer()
tokenizer_encoder.fit_on_texts(input_grams)
input_data = tokenizer_encoder.texts_to_sequences(input_grams)
input_data = sequence.pad_sequences(input_data, maxlen=maxlen_seq, padding='post')

tokenizer_decoder = Tokenizer(char_level=True)
tokenizer_decoder.fit_on_texts(target_seqs)
target_data = tokenizer_decoder.texts_to_sequences(target_seqs)
target_data = sequence.pad_sequences(target_data, maxlen=maxlen_seq, padding='post')
target_data = to_categorical(target_data)
input_data.shape, target_data.shape

from keras.models import Model, Input
from keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, Dense, TimeDistributed, Bidirectional

n_words = len(tokenizer_encoder.word_index) + 1
n_tags = len(tokenizer_decoder.word_index) + 1
print(n_words, n_tags)

input = Input(shape=(maxlen_seq,))
x = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=128, input_length=maxlen_seq)(input)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(x)
y = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="softmax"))(x)
model = Model(input, y)
model.summary()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.metrics import categorical_accuracy
from keras import backend  as K
import tensorflow as tf

def q3_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    y = tf.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
    y_ = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
    mask = tf.greater(y, 0)
    return K.cast(K.equal(tf.boolean_mask(y, mask), tf.boolean_mask(y_, mask)), K.floatx())

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy", q3_acc])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(input_data, target_data, test_size=.4, random_state=0)
seq_train, seq_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(input_seqs, target_seqs, test_size=.4, random_state=0)

#model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=5, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1)

def onehot_to_seq(oh_seq, index):
    s = ''
    for o in oh_seq:
        i = np.argmax(o)
        if i != 0:
            s += index[i]
        else:
            break
    return s

def plot_results(x, y, y_):
    print("---")
    print("Input: " + str(x))
    print("Target: " + str(onehot_to_seq(y, revsere_decoder_index).upper()))
    print("Result: " + str(onehot_to_seq(y_, revsere_decoder_index).upper()))
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))
    plt.imshow(y.T, cmap='Blues')
    plt.imshow(y_.T, cmap='Reds', alpha=.5)
    plt.yticks(range(4), [' '] + [revsere_decoder_index[i+1].upper() for i in range(3)])
    plt.show()

revsere_decoder_index = {value:key for key,value in tokenizer_decoder.word_index.items()}
revsere_encoder_index = {value:key for key,value in tokenizer_encoder.word_index.items()}

#N=3
#y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train[:N])
#y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test[:N])
#print('training')
#for i in range(N):
#    plot_results(seq_train[i], y_train[i], y_train_pred[i])
#print('testing')
#for i in range(N):
#    plot_results(seq_test[i], y_test[i], y_test_pred[i])

loaded_model = pickle.load(open( "save.p", "rb" )) 

N=3
y_train_pred = loaded_model.predict(X_train[:N])
y_test_pred = loaded_model.predict(X_test[:N])
print('training')
for i in range(N):
    plot_results(seq_train[i], y_train[i], y_train_pred[i])
print('testing')
for i in range(N):
    plot_results(seq_test[i], y_test[i], y_test_pred[i])

#print(type(target_seqs))
```

CODE WHICH DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED:

In this, 'xf' is the csv file which has the sequences for which I require the predictions.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\2018-06-06-ss.cleaned.csv')
xf = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\sequence.csv')
df.len.hist(bins=100)
print(df.shape)

def seq2ngrams(seqs, n=3):
    return np.array([[seq[i:i+n] for i in range(len(seq))] for seq in seqs])

maxlen_seq = 128
input_seqs, target_seqs = df[['seq', 'sst3']][(df.len <= maxlen_seq) & (~df.has_nonstd_aa)].values.T
input_grams = seq2ngrams(input_seqs)
print(len(input_seqs))

from keras.preprocessing import text, sequence
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.utils import to_categorical

tokenizer_encoder = Tokenizer()
tokenizer_encoder.fit_on_texts(input_grams)
input_data = tokenizer_encoder.texts_to_sequences(input_grams)
input_data = sequence.pad_sequences(input_data, maxlen=maxlen_seq, padding='post')

tokenizer_decoder = Tokenizer(char_level=True)
tokenizer_decoder.fit_on_texts(target_seqs)
target_data = tokenizer_decoder.texts_to_sequences(target_seqs)
target_data = sequence.pad_sequences(target_data, maxlen=maxlen_seq, padding='post')
target_data = to_categorical(target_data)
input_data.shape, target_data.shape

from keras.models import Model, Input
from keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, Dense, TimeDistributed, Bidirectional

n_words = len(tokenizer_encoder.word_index) + 1
n_tags = len(tokenizer_decoder.word_index) + 1
print(n_words, n_tags)

input = Input(shape=(maxlen_seq,))
x = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=128, input_length=maxlen_seq)(input)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(x)
y = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="softmax"))(x)
model = Model(input, y)
model.summary()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.metrics import categorical_accuracy
from keras import backend  as K
import tensorflow as tf

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy")

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(input_data, target_data, test_size=.4, random_state=0)
seq_train, seq_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(input_seqs, target_seqs, test_size=.4, random_state=0)

#model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1)

def onehot_to_seq(oh_seq, index):
    s = ''
    for o in oh_seq:
        i = np.argmax(o)
        if i != 0:
            s += index[i]
        else:
            break
    return s

def plot_results(x, y, y_):
    print("---")
    print("Input: " + str(x))
    print("Target: " + str(onehot_to_seq(y, revsere_decoder_index).upper()))
    print("Result: " + str(onehot_to_seq(y_, revsere_decoder_index).upper()))
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))
    plt.imshow(y.T, cmap='Blues')
    plt.imshow(y_.T, cmap='Reds', alpha=.5)
    plt.yticks(range(4), [' '] + [revsere_decoder_index[i+1].upper() for i in range(3)])
    plt.show()

revsere_decoder_index = {value:key for key,value in tokenizer_decoder.word_index.items()}
revsere_encoder_index = {value:key for key,value in tokenizer_encoder.word_index.items()}

N=3
y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train[:N])
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test[:N])
print('training')
for i in range(N):
    plot_results(seq_train[i], y_train[i], y_train_pred[i])
print('testing')
for i in range(N):
    plot_results(seq_test[i], y_test[i], y_test_pred[i])

loaded_model = pickle.load(open( "save.p", "rb" )) 

N=3
y_train_pred = loaded_model.predict(X_train[:N])
y_test_pred = loaded_model.predict(X_test[:N])
print('training')
for i in range(N):
    plot_results(seq_train[i], y_train[i], y_train_pred[i])
print('testing')
for i in range(N):
    plot_results(seq_test[i], y_test[i], y_test_pred[i])

print("-----")
print(X_test[:3])
print("-----")

xf.len.hist(bins=100)
input_seqs1, target_seqs1 = xf[['seq', 'sst3']][(xf.len <= maxlen_seq) & (~xf.has_nonstd_aa)].values.T
input_grams1 = seq2ngrams(input_seqs1)

tokenizer_encoder1 = Tokenizer()
tokenizer_encoder1.fit_on_texts(input_grams1)
input_data1 = tokenizer_encoder1.texts_to_sequences(input_grams1)
input_data1 = sequence.pad_sequences(input_data1, maxlen=maxlen_seq, padding='post')

tokenizer_decoder1 = Tokenizer(char_level=True)
tokenizer_decoder1.fit_on_texts(target_seqs1)
target_data1 = tokenizer_decoder1.texts_to_sequences(target_seqs1)
target_data1 = sequence.pad_sequences(target_data1, maxlen=maxlen_seq, padding='post')
target_data1 = to_categorical(target_data1)
input_data1.shape, target_data1.shape

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(input_data1, target_data1, test_size=1, random_state=0)
seq_train, seq_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(input_seqs1, target_seqs1, test_size=1, random_state=0)

y_train_pred1 = loaded_model.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred1 = loaded_model.predict(X_test)
plot_results(seq_train, y_train, y_train_pred)
plot_results(seq_test, y_test, y_test_pred)

#print(input_data1[0])
##y_train_pred = loaded_model.predict(input_data)
#y_test_pred1 = loaded_model.predict(input_data1[0])
##plot_results(seq_train, y_train, y_train_pred)
#plot_results(input_seqs1, target_data1, y_test_pred1)
```

TRACEBACK:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-38-e8f27dda0841>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Viktor/Desktop/rost_nocl.py', wdir='C:/Users/Viktor/Desktop')

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Viktor/Desktop/rost_nocl.py", line 116, in <module>
    tokenizer_encoder1.fit_on_texts(input_grams1)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py", line 223, in fit_on_texts
    self.split)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py", line 43, in text_to_word_sequence
    text = text.lower()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Which line do you see the error? Please provide the full stack trace

Comment: The code above works fine as it does the prediction from the objects created through test_train_split. It is when I try to create a numpy.ndarray object from a custom sequence (say a csv file <same format as dataset> with just one/two or more sequence(s) which I want to test) that I get the error.

Adding one of my attempts at this with the traceback in the main question.